# Manage Azure AD Authentication getting windows Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

I follow this [Microsoft Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore/) to put a Microsoft office 365 authentication in my WPF Application and WEB API.
All works perfectly, the user open the app and a microsoft popup is shown.
After the login the user is able to use my WEB API.
Now, along with this solution, i would like to get the windows credential and authenticate the users automatically in Azure AD.

Most of the time, my user is under the same azure tenant domains, so i would like to authenticate it automatically without user interactions.

Is it a possible Solution or windows authentication can't speak with azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution watching better in Microsoft Docs:
"
**Acquiring a token with Windows Integrated security**
If your PC is domain joined or AAD joined, you can also use the Windows-integrated security. For this, instead of calling TextualPrompt(), you need to uncomment the line creating an instance of UserCredential without parameters: See Program.cs

UserCredential uc = new UserCredential();
You can trigger the middleware to send an OpenID Connect sign-in request by decorating a class or method with the [Authorize] attribute
"